# Looking for the Outdated Dependency

Tags: pallet

I am updating our pallet's for the first time in (1-2) years. I have been trying to iron out all of the outdated dependancies for the last couple of days. I can't seem to get past this error which I have been having:

```
error: failed to select a version for `parity-util-mem`.
    ... required by package `sp-runtime v6.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.26#e8a7d161)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `sp-runtime` of package `frame-benchmarking v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.26#e8a7d161)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `frame-benchmarking` of package `pallet-vesting v4.0.0 (/Users/jackson/Desktop/chain_v2/pallets/vesting)`
    ... which satisfies path dependency `pallet-vesting` of package `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/Users/jackson/Desktop/chain_v2/runtime)`
    ... which satisfies path dependency `node-template-runtime` (locked to 4.0.0-dev) of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/Users/jackson/Desktop/chain_v2/node)`
versions that meet the requirements `^0.11.0` are: 0.11.0

the package `parity-util-mem` links to the native library `parity-util-mem-ban-duplicates`, but it conflicts with a previous package which links to `parity-util-mem-ban-duplicates` as well:
package `parity-util-mem v0.10.2`
    ... which satisfies dependency `parity-util-mem = "^0.10.2"` of package `sc-service v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?tag=devhub/latest#22d40c76)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `sc-service` (locked to 0.10.0-dev) of package `frame-benchmarking-cli v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?tag=devhub/latest#22d40c76)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `frame-benchmarking-cli` (locked to 4.0.0-dev) of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/Users/jackson/Desktop/chain_v2/node)`
Only one package in the dependency graph may specify the same links value. This helps ensure that only one copy of a native library is linked in the final binary. Try to adjust your dependencies so that only one package uses the links ='parity-util-mem' value. For more information, see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html#links.

failed to select a version for `parity-util-mem` which could resolve this conflict
```

This is the Cargo.toml file which is being compiled:

```
[package]
name = "pallet-vesting"
version = "4.0.0"
description = "FRAME pallet template for defining custom runtime logic."
authors = ["Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>"]
homepage = "https://substrate.io/"
edition = "2021"
license = "Unlicense"
publish = false
repository = "https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/"

[package.metadata.docs.rs]
targets = ["x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"]

[dependencies]
parity-scale-codec = { version = "3.0.0", default-features = false, features = [ "derive" ] }
scale-info = { version = "2.0", default-features = false, features = [
    "derive"
] }
frame-support = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.26", default-features = false }
frame-system = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.26", default-features = false }
frame-benchmarking = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.26", default-features = false }
sp-runtime = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.26", default-features = false }
sp-std = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.26", default-features = false }

[dev-dependencies]
sp-core = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.26" }
sp-io = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.26" }
orml-utilities = {version = "0.4.1-dev", git = "https://github.com/open-web3-stack/open-runtime-module-library.git"}
pallet-balances = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.26" }

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "parity-scale-codec/std",
    "scale-info/std",
    "frame-support/std",
    "frame-system/std",
    "frame-benchmarking/std",
]
runtime-benchmarks = ["frame-benchmarking/runtime-benchmarks"]
try-runtime = ["frame-support/try-runtime"]
```

Is there a way to tell which dependency is the issue? If there is how would I update it. Thanks in advance for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

Dependency that causes the problem is written in error, so you can follow the report to find remaining outdated packages.

In this case, it says that one version of `parity-util-mem` is required by `pallet-vesting` .toml of which you have attached, and another one comes from `frame-benchmarking-cli` which is (together with `vesting`) is a dependency of  `node-template`.

So updating `frame-benchmarking-cli`'s git version somewhere in `/Users/jackson/Desktop/chain_v2/node/Cargo.toml` to `branch = "polkadot-v0.9.26"` should do the work (if I'm not missing something)